# How to Prevent Guile from Starting a Debugger for Every Error?

Tags: debugging, emacs, scheme, guile, geiser

I am using [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) in conjunction with [Geiser](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/) under Emacs while learning how to program in Scheme. I find it actually a hindrance that Guile drops into a debugger each time I make a typo or enter a wrong piece of code. How can I make Guile more tolerant of my typos/errors and skip the debugger, while using it through Geiser under Emacs?

As I get more advanced in Scheme programming, how would I restore the default behavior or else how can I toggle between having the debugger always start vs start only on demand?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `on-error` option to `report`, and it will simply report the error without dropping you in the debugger (that's the default value, `debug`); e.g.

```
scheme@(guile-user)> ,option on-error 'report
scheme@(guile-user)> (/ 1 0)
ERROR: Throw to key `numerical-overflow' with args `("/" "Numerical overflow" #f #f)'.
scheme@(guile-user)>
```

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/System-Commands.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't really write a lot of Scheme, but it seems that you can just ignore the debugger.

If you're using [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) to do the
eval with <kbd>e</kbd>, you don't even see the REPL window, you just
get messages in the echo area with the result.

If you set `(setq geiser-impl--implementation 'guile)`, and press
<kbd>e</kbd> in `lispy-mode`, it will start a Geiser REPL
automatically (if there isn't a live one) and eval the expression.